# Cannot see partitions in fdisk utility

Tags: partition, fdisk

I've been struggling with this couple of hours now.

Deleted all existing partitions and created a new one on (virtually unmounted) removable USB media using:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb1

Command (m for help): n

Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-30296063, default 2048): 2048
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-30296063, default 30296063): 30296063
Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 14,5 GiB.
```

and then changed partition type using:

```
Command (m for help): t
Hex code (type L to list all codes): c
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'W95 FAT32 (LBA)'.
```

applied changes:

```
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

informing kernel for changes:

```
$ sudo partprobe
```

So far so good. After that, i've created FAT32 filesystem on the new partition:

```
$ sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
```

mounting the device to virtual directory:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/xxx
```

Everything seems to be okay but when i want to check partitions on the device again using fdisk utility:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb1
Disk /dev/sdb1: 14,5 GiB, 15511584768 bytes, 30296064 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

ends up with strange disk identifier and no partition table at all (why?). But when i run this command:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 14,5 GiB, 15518924800 bytes, 30310400 sectors
Disk model: TransMemory     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x03eba3c3

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 30298111 30296064 14,5G  b W95 FAT32
```

yep, partition table is here but partition type is W95 FAT32 instead of W95 FAT32 (LBA). so what am i doing wrong? is this behaviour normal?

Comment: `fdisk` operates on the disk as a whole, and not the individual partotions. I.e., use `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`.

Comment: i am an idiot. thanks for correctly pointing out. this should be the correct answer. post this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fdisk` operates on the disk as a whole, and not the individual partitions. I.e., use `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`.